# How to resolve "Warning: Deprecated syntax `parametric method syntax Base.show{S}" in Julia

Tags: julia

I am updating my code from Julia v0.6 to v0.7.  I get the following error at runtime:

```
 Warning: Deprecated syntax `parametric method syntax Base.show{S (io::IO, m::Base.MIME("text/plain"), scvec::Vector{StatesContainer{S}}) around /Users/logankilpatrick/.julia/packages/SHERPA/A8APz/src/utils/states_containers.jl:74.
```

Use `Base.show(io::IO, m::Base.MIME("text/plain"), scvec::Vector{StatesContainer{S}}) where S` instead.

So I do the following:

Original code: `Base.show{S}(io::IO, m::Base.MIME("text/plain"), scvec::Vector{StatesContainer{S}})`

Updated Code: `function Base.show(io::IO, m::Base.MIME("text/plain"), scvec::Vector{StatesContainer{S}}) where S`

I still get the following error: `ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: ArgumentError: invalid type for argument m in method definition for show at /Users/logankilpatrick/.julia/packages/SHERPA/A8APz/src/utils/states_containers.jl:74`

All line 74 shows is: `println(io, typeof(scvec))`

Any suggestions as to how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Note: I tried commenting out what was on line 74, and re-running it.  It then said there was an issue with line 76!

I also tried getting rid of the "where S" part at the end of the function but that doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct signature is:

```
Base.show(io::IO, m::MIME{Symbol("text/plain")}, scvec::Vector{StatesContainer{S}}) where S
```

Comment: Thank you!  It was showing that earlier, and then for some reason changed the suggestion this morning to what I showed above. Maybe it's a bug or I just may be incompetent.

Comment: Hard to tell - I moved to Julia 1.0 some time ago (but Julia 0.7 is compatible with it so I knew what is the answer :)).

Comment: check out the link to my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746868/julia-error-loaderror-argumenterror-package-xxxx-does-not-have-excelreaders-i