# Julia ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package xxxx does not have ExcelReaders in its dependencies:

Tags: julia

So I have upgraded to Julia v0.7 from v0.6.  I am trying to convert my code.  I get the following error:

`ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package xxx does not have ExcelReaders in its dependencies:
- If you have xxx checked out for development and have
  added ExcelReaders as a dependency but haven't updated your primary environment's manifest file, try Pkg.resolve().
- Otherwise, you may need to report an issue with xxx`

So I did an `add ExcelReaders` and `resolve` and I just get a warning instead:

```
 Warning: Package xxx does not have ExcelReaders in its dependencies:
If you have xxx checked out for development and have
added ExcelReaders as a dependency but haven't updated your primary
environment's manifest file, try Pkg.resolve().
- Otherwise you may need to report an issue with SHERPA
Loading ExcelReaders into xxx from project dependency, future warnings for xxx are suppressed.
```

How can I fix this issue? In one of my files, I do `using ExcelReaders, DataFrames, DataArrays`.

I have the same issue for all 3.  I add them, and then I still get the warning.  For DataArrays specifically, I get a bunch of depreciation and actually a syntax error if I add the DataArrays Package.

Thanks!

Note: This [link](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataArrays.jl) talks about the depreciation of DataArrays.  I use `data = DataArrays.data` in my code, so if I stop doing `using DataArrays`, it obviously won't work and it's not clear what the replacement would be.

Update: DataArrays is deprecated so I got rid of the line "data = DataArrays.data".  I added ExcelReaders and DataFrames and then did a resolve and I guess it fixed the issue.

Comment: I did not dig into all the errors but you will run into multiple different things during the process if you use those packages as they have changed significantly. What I can tell for sure is that DataArrays.jl was released one year ago last time and is deprecated so I would not recommend using it at all. Also ExcelReaders dropped support for DataFrames.jl and ExcelFiles.jl provides it. In general I would recommend you to study the GitHub repos of respective packages to find out about their state and recommended usage pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Package xxx does not have ExcelReaders in its dependencies` means that `xxxx` does not have `ExcelReaders` in its dependencies (it is unrelated with the fact if you have installed `ExcelReaders` manually). I do not know what `xxxx` is so it is hard to check.

See https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/Pkg/#Adding-dependencies-to-the-project-1 for the details.

Comment: xxxx is just a placeholder for a project I am working on. I will look at the link tho.

Comment: The link says that if I add the package, it gets added as a dependency.  So if I add Excel Readers, DataFrames, and DataArrays, I should theoretically not have an issue anymore assuming I do a "Resolve".

Comment: AFAIK you have to add it when your project is activated so that appropriate entries are added to Project.toml and Manifest.toml.

Comment: hello @Bogumil,  I am still having this issue with other packages.  How do I get the warning to go away?

Comment: It is hard to help without having a reproducible example, which in this case ideally should cover: 1) precisely what steps do you do, 2) what Project.toml and Manifest.toml of your project contain and 3) what is exactly the error message.

Comment: I was having this issue with POMDPSimulators and I did `up PODMPSimulators` and it resolved the issue.  But now it shows Warning: Package SHERPA does not have FileIO in its dependencies.  I tried the update, resolve, and build, but to no avail.

Comment: In my manifest file, I have the following: [FileIO]]
deps = ["Pkg", "Random", "Test"]
git-tree-sha1 = "481e4db939f005db39f7296599d0543c0744fe30"
uuid = "5789e2e9-d7fb-5bc7-8068-2c6fae9b9549"
version = "1.0.2"

Comment: I also see FileIO in the project.toml file.

Comment: As I have said above - given this is an apparently complex case I am not able to help without a reproducible example. Maybe someone able will be able to guess what is the reason of the problem.