# Warning: Package xxxxx does not have POMDPSimulators in its dependencies in Julia if usual recommendations don't work.

Tags: julia

I have seen this issue commonly since I started the transition to Julia v0.7 from v0.6. I am getting the following warning:

```
 Warning: Package xxxxx does not have POMDPSimulators in its dependencies:
│ - If you have xxxxx checked out for development and have
│   added POMDPSimulators as a dependency but haven't updated your primary
│   environment's manifest file, try `Pkg.resolve()`.
│ - Otherwise you may need to report an issue with xxxxx
└ Loading POMDPSimulators into xxxxx from project dependency, future warnings for xxxxx are suppressed.
```

I do not understand why I get this warning.  In one of my files, I do: `using POMDPSimulators`.  Since I typed in that, I have done a `resolve` in the Pkg manager, and done a `build POMDPSimulators` in the package manager.  This doesn't change the warning.  How can I get rid of this warning?

Note: xxxxx is just the name of a file/project that is removed to make this post general.

Note: I asked a similar question here: [[Julia ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package xxxx does not have ExcelReaders in its dependencies:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746868/julia-error-loaderror-argumenterror-package-xxxx-does-not-have-excelreaders-i][1)

I already checked out the Julia documentation and did what it says.  I added the package to the project by using the package manager and typing `add POMDPSimulators`.

Any suggestions to resolve this issue?

Note: If possible, I am looking for a general answer since I think I am going to have this issue with other packages as well.  If there is any other documentation out there besides what was provided by JuliaLang I could appreciate that since I didn't find it helpful.

[Link to the Julia Article about dependencies](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/Pkg/#Adding-dependencies-to-the-project-1)

**I tried a pkg> update, build, and resolve.  The issue isn't resolved. I see the file in my Manifest and Project file.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Julia ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package xxxx does not have ExcelReaders in its dependencies:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746868/julia-error-loaderror-argumenterror-package-xxxx-does-not-have-excelreaders-i). If the answer there was not satisfactory it is better you ask for clarification there.

Comment: I don't think it was a duplicate.  That issue was resolved by doing something else.  I would delete that question, but I think there is tangible knowledge to be gained by someone looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what got the Warning to no longer show for me.

Go to your require file and type "NameOfPackageGivingWarning" on a new line.

Click "]" in Julia to open the package manager in Julia command line version:

`up NameOfPackageGivingWarning`

```
build NameOfPackageGivingWarning
```

`resolve`

```
activate NameOfPackageGivingWarning
```

This should resolve the issue for you. I am honestly unsure why this works and I may be taking more steps than necessary, but it resolved the issue for all of my package dependency warnings!

Comment: What do you mean by "go to your require file"? Is this the Project.toml file? Manifest.toml?

Comment: Yes, the require file was replaced by the Project.toml file.